# Build a WAR with Web Services to deploy on Tomcat Server, with maven

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, tomcat, cxf

So i'm builiding a server with Soap Web-Services, using CXF.
Until now, i was building my WAR with ANT, so I was able to add manually a list of Jar libraries (all get from CXF libraries) needed to deploy a Web Project where CXF Libaries is needed.
Now I'm building my war with Maven. There are no errors while WAR's generation, but this new WAR doesn't contain all needed libraries.

For exemple, this what I'm getting where I'm trying to deploy this new WAR built with Maven:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4876)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

i'm understanding that spring libraries are required here, and I was able to add them with ANT, but what should I do with maven?

Comment: Add the required jar file to the CP using Maven. You need to add dependency that is mentioned in the error. If you go to the mavencentral and search using the package name, you might find the dependancy u r looking for